# DatabaseError at /blog/ No exception message supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

i am new in django and i need your help,
others pages are working well but when i click into blog pages it shows DatabaseError at /blog/
No exception message supplied and i below i have attached the views.py and modeles.py code

// Code views.py :

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from .meta_gen import meta_keywords

def indexblog(request):
"""
Display Blog  page

```
        **Context**

        ``indexblog``
            An instance of :model:`indexblog.Course`

        **Templates**
        :template:`pages/blog.html`
    """
blogs = Blog.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(is_published=True)
context = {
    'blogs': blogs
}

return render(request, 'pages/blog.html', context)
```

def blog(request, blog_id):
"""
Display Blog detail page

```
    **Context**

    ``blog``
        An instance of :model:`Blog.blog`

    **Templates**
    :template:`pages/bloginside.html`
"""
blogdetails = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
blogs = Blog.objects.all()
context = {
    'blogdetails': blogdetails,
    'blogs': blogs
}
return render(request, 'pages/bloginside.html', context)
```

this_template = "apptemplate.html"

def tabs(request):
return render(request, {'title': "Blog", 'keys': meta_keywords(render_to_string(this_template))})

// code models.py
from django.db import models

from datetime import datetime
from django.urls import reverse
from pages.img_compression import compressImage

class Blog(models.Model):
"""
Blog Model

```
Fields
    blog_title
    blog_tag
    blog_image
    blog_describe
    is_published
    list_date
    ....rest
"""
blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=700)
blog_tag = models.CharField(max_length=400)
blog_image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=False, max_length=500)
author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
blog_describe = models.TextField(blank=False)
is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.blog_title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blogs', args=[self.id, ])

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    compressed_image = compressImage(self.blog_image)
    self.blog_image = compressed_image
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: what is data base you have been working?

Comment: I have used MongoDB Atlas @daneilJames

Comment: Once try to run your db in shell and try to Blog.objects.all() see if it get correct and try to add db configuration for mongo db too in qsn